# Google Script: getValues() and setValues() for rectangular grid

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

In Google Sheets, when I store a given a1notation into an appendRow, I want the values from this appended Row to be shown on another sheet while retaining the grid structure it had when it was saved intitially.

So from the below code, the data from the appendedRow(11,5,1,5) shall be set to the grid I5:J7.

Sadly I am not proficient enough to work with `for` loops and `push()` / array, so I would appreciate your support greatly.

Thank you.

```
function Test() {
  var rs = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ss = rs.getSheetByName("Sheet");

  var tempArray = [ss.getRange(11,5,1,5)]
  var values = tempArray.getValues();

  ss.getRange('I5:J7').setValues(values);
}
```

Comment: Your `ss.getRange(11,5,1,5)` gives you a 1x5 grid, but your destination range ('I5:J7') is giving you a 2x3 grid.

Comment: Please show your script that contains `appendRow()`, also your `tempArray` is pointless because `getValues()` returns an array anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Apps Script documentation has a Reference section which gives you a brief explanation and example of different methods. Under

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues

you can see that the method setValues(values) requires the dimension of the origin and destination range to match. Thus, you cannot paste a 1x5 range into a 2x3 range.

What you can do is to loop through the cells of the destination range and to assign them sequentially a value from the origin range - until either all the values have been passed or the destination range is full. You could implement it like this:

```
function Test() {
  var rs = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ss = rs.getSheetByName("Sheet");

  var values = ss.getRange(11,5,1,5).getValues();
  var destination=ss.getRange('I5:J7');
  var value=0;
  for(i=1;i<=3;i++)
  {
    for(j=1;j<=2;j++)
    {
      var cell=destination.getCell(i,j);
      if(typeof values[0][value] !== "undefined")
      {
        cell.setValue(values[0][value]);
      }
      value=value+1;
    }
  }  
}
```

Comment: In my code i loops through the rows and j through the columns of the destination range. Depending on the dimension of the range, you would adjust the maximum values for the rows and columns accordingly (e.g. if you have 37 rows, then it's   for(i=1;i<=37;i++))

Comment: Thank you very much Ziganotschka. I figured the answer out myself and thus erased my comment but of course you read it in the meanwhile. :)

Thank you all again, It means a lot to me.